# Alternative to C header file S.h

Tags: c++, r

I am a beginner to C++ and I am looking at a C file that uses S.h header. I have been asked to do the following:

> The R core team notified us that they're removing C header file S.h from R. This means that package would need to be modified to not rely on S.h anymore.

Following is the syntax from the file:

```
#include <S.h>
```

I am not sure what that header is and how to change it accordingly to find an alternative.

Comment: Start by consulting the documentation from the folks at R and see if they have a migration path defined that you can follow. If they don't, remove the include and compile. Make a list of all of the stuff that fails to compile. Hunt replacements for the pieces you're actually using.

Answer (score 2):

Directly from `S.h` in the [R Source repository on Github](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/include/S.h), lines 33-37:

```
// Defer until 2022-03-15
// #warning "Legacy header S.h is no longer supported: use R.h instead"

/* This header includes C headers and so is not safe for inclusion
   from C++: use R.h instead. */
```

It would appear the correct solution is to include `R.h` instead of `S.h`, and rewrite any code that relies upon constructs that were not ported from `S.h` to `R.h`.